# Calculate proportion (percent) for each column of a dataset

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the proportion (percent) of categories in each column of a dataset.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    "Size" = c("Y","N","N","Y","Y"), 
    "Type" =  c("N","N","N","Y","N"), 
    "Age" = c("N","Y","N","Y","N"), 
    "Sex"=c("N","N","N","N","N")
  )

df
```

Data produces a table like this:

```
    Size Type Age Sex
1    Y    N   N   N
2    N    N   Y   N
3    N    N   N   N
4    Y    Y   Y   N
5    Y    N   N   N
```

I've tried using prop.table to calculate proportion for one category:

```
prop.table(table(df$Size))
```

This works, but only calculates the percent of Y or N answers for one column. This dataset is quite large, so I'd like to calculate the proportion for each category at once.

My goal is to have a table that shows the proportion of "yes" answers for each column.

Like this:

```
       Proportion Y
Size    0.60
Type    0.20
Age     0.40
Sex     0.00
```

I am relatively new to R, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise_all(~mean(.=="Y"))
```

If you have more than one group:

```
df1 = data.frame(class="A",df)
df2 = data.frame(class="B",df)
#make df2 different
df2$Size<- rep("Y",5)
newdf = rbind(df1,df2)
newdf %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise_all(~mean(.=="Y"))
```

Comment: This works! Is there a way to make the output a table like above instead of lines of text?

Comment: It's a data.frame, I mean you can store it results <- df %>% summarise_all(~mean(.=="Y"))

Comment: do you mean this: t(df %>% summarise_all(~mean(.=="Y")))

Comment: Yes, adding the t in front makes it easier to export, thanks!

Comment: Say I want to summarize by group as well. 

Ex. I have group A and B, which both have Y and N data for size, type, age and sex.

Is there a way to get the proportion of Y for just group A? Thanks!

Comment: hi @jl748795, yes you can. use group_by; see my edited post above

Answer (score 3):

One way in base R would be to use `apply` column-wise on a logical vector

```
apply(df == "Y", 2, mean)

#Size Type  Age  Sex 
# 0.6  0.2  0.4  0.0
```

A simpler version with `colSums`.

```
colMeans(df == "Y")
```